# $E[\hat{\theta}_{MME}] = E[\frac{1- 2\overline{y}}{\overline{y}-1}] = \int_0^1 \frac{1- 2\overline{y}}{\overline{y}-1}(\theta+1)y^\theta dy$..?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $Y_1, Y_2,\dots , Y_n$ denote a random sample from the probability density function

$$f (y | θ)=\begin{cases} (θ + 1)y^θ, &  0 < y < 1; θ > −1,\\ 0 ,& \text{elsewhere}.\end{cases}$$

I found the $\theta$ by using Method of Moment (MME)

$$
\begin{align}
\hat{\theta}&=\frac{1- 2\overline{y}}{\overline{y}-1}\\
\end{align}
$$

Then I want to find

$$E[\hat{\theta}_{MME}] = E[\frac{1- 2\overline{y}}{\overline{y}-1}] = \int_0^1 \frac{1- 2\overline{y}}{\overline{y}-1}(\theta+1)y^\theta dy$$...How do I go from here since the y are different?

Answer (score 0):

When the $Y_i$s are independant and with distribution density $f$,
then for every $F$,  $E[F(Y_1, \dots , Y_n)]
= \int dy_1 f(y_1) \dots \int dy_n f(y_n) F( y_1, \dots , y_n)$.

Here this is just an application with $F( y_1, \dots , y_n) = 
\frac 1n (y_1+ \cdots + y_n)$.

---

The integral is wrong. It should be

$$\int dy_1 \dots \int dy_n (\theta+1)^n (y_1\dots y_n)^\theta
\frac {n-2(y_1+\dots +y_n)}{y_1+\dots +y_n - n}
$$

Comment: could you explain how you set up this integral? what is the reason behind it?

Comment: the reason: $\overline y$ does depend on every $y_i$. As they are independant, the density of $(y_1, \dots ,y_n)$ is the product of the densities.

Comment: why the y in $(\theta+1)y^\theta$ become $\bar{y}$?

Comment: I have not integrated anything like this before, infinite terms within a integral...could you provide several more steps?

Comment: because you don't know the density of $\line y$, just the density of $(y_1 \dots y_n)$

Comment: I added the general case, I hope it will help

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf: there is just a finite number of terms here. the whole thing looks messy, but I would not have written an integral with an infinite number of variables ;)

Comment: Can i first find $$\int_0^1 (\theta+1)^n (y)^\theta
\frac {1-2y}{y-1} dy$$. After I found the integral, I raise to the power of n sine they are i.i.d.

Comment: I let you read my answer again.

Comment: I first calculate one of the y, 
$$E[\hat{\theta}_{MME}] = E[\frac{2{y}-1}{1- {y}}] = E[\frac{1}{1- {y}}-2] =\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1- {y}}(\theta+1)y^\theta dy - 2$$... However, i found they are  not integrable. Are these right? If so, they are just unbounded?